# How to get ImageRendition Size?

Tags: java, freemarker, magnolia

I want to retrieve the **height and width** of an image in magnolia **after it has been scaled/cropped** by the imageprocessor (ImageVariations) but I don't seem to find the correct methods for that.

Here is one definition I made in theme.yaml:

```
imaging:
  class: info.magnolia.templating.imaging.VariationAwareImagingSupport
  variations:
    "large":
      class: info.magnolia.templating.imaging.variation.SimpleResizeVariation
      width: 745
  [...]
```

What I do is the following:

- In my template (FTL) I am first fetching the JCR Key by writing `[#assign
  itemKey = content.backgroundImage!""]`.
- I am using the DamFunctions to retrieve the asset by it's key
  with `damfn.getAsset(itemKey);`
- I am fetching the rendition (which I understand as the scaled version of the image) with `dam.getRendition(asset, renditionName)`

I can read width and height from the AssetMetaData, but even when using the Rendition object I still get the *original* asset metadata, not as expected, the scaled ones.

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Can you have a look at this picture, please? It shows the path I would use to retrieve the maxwidth and maxheight. Please tell me it is possible to go that way.

[image: /modules/imaging/config/generators/large/operations/resize@maxWidth]

*Thanks for your help!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With DAM API 1.x, `Rendition` you got back was just extending asset and doing nothing about metadata thus the meta you get back is indeed meta data of the original asset.
With DAM API 2.x it got slightly better where `Rendition` now recognizes that meta data of rendition are not the same as that of original asset, however it doesn't provide correct meta either and just throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.
So you are stuck either way. From your description, I presume you are using some older version of Magnolia where DAM 1.x is still used.

As for the solution to your problem, the only way to know the size of the image rendition is to know how variation that you use will affect the image.
To obtain it dynamically, you would need to get hold of `Imaging` object, figure out which image generator shall be used (can be found as part of the path of rendition link), get correct generator from `Imaging`, most likely it would be instance of `ImageOperationChain` and you would need to feed it your original image plus all the ops that are specified as part of the rendition you want, let it do it's work, then read width/height from produced buffered image and then throw all that away. It would be terribly inefficient to do during rendering of template.

Edit:
If you want to read configuration directly from the imaging module, you would need to read it via JCR API and make sure you do so in system context as normal user has no access to such info (or shouldn't have anyway).
Something like `${ctx.getSystemContext().getJCRSession("config").getNode("/modules/imaging/config/generators/large/operations/resize").getProperty("maxWidth").getString()}` should do. But it still requires you to know what generator will be used and just gives you parameters for the generator, not guaranteeing it will modify the resource in given way. E.g. in this case if width of asset is less than `maxWidth`, image will not be resized to rendered asset width will be less than 1300. But I guess you already know that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jan! But can I simply use the name of the rendition (variant) to figure out it's max width so I could do a division based on that and get the height I need?

Comment: Somehow, yes. Ideally, obtain site from current state, then use it to get current theme and from theme get imaging and all listed variations. But imaging doesn't expose list of configured variations to outside. What you need to do instead is, once you find the theme name via `${state.site.theme.name}` get that name and obtain theme node (assuming your theme still lives in repository) and read variations from there. If your theme is configured in light module and lives in file system, you are most likely stuck.

Comment: I edited my answer and added a picture showing the path I would use. Yes, I am using YAML Configuration for the theme. Do you think there's a way to retrieve property value behind that node path using NodeUtil or something? Or is that what you meant by 'imaging doesn't expose list of configured variations to outside'? The other path I see is '/modules/site/config/themes/"+siteTheme.getName()+"/imaging/variations' ...

Comment: Edited answer in response to edited question. Access to variations under "theme" is out for you because you use light module and there's no means to access file system and read file and there's no object representing those variations for you to be consumed exposed anywhere by system either. All you can do is read info from imaging generators, but you need to know which variation/rendition will be pointed to which generator.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jan! You really helped me a lot so far. Please allow me one more question: Is it possible to extend a YAML-Theme via JCR-Configuration or vice versa? I would like to have my theming resources (js, css) on filesystem and my imaging variations in JCR.

Comment: ...and I guess what's inside "Definitions" is not visible to my code?

Comment: You should be able to inherit from jcr based theme in your YAML theme but not vice versa https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Reusing+configuration

Comment: “Definitions” show content of registries. Whether or not you can see what’s inside depends on given registry implementation.